# JQuery ScrollTop works on chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, scrolltop

I have a simple JS/Jquery script that allows the user to navigate (via hash menu links and ScrollTop) to a specific part of a page section (in this case, the /guides/ section). The script works just fine on Chrome. On Firefox however, it doesn't seem to be getting triggered.

As of this writing, my chrome version is: 45.0.2454.85
and my firefox is 40.0.3

The URL to the site in question: genesistutorials101.com
The links with hashes can be found under MENU.
The script I have running:

```
//HASH # NAV
$(function(){

 if (window.location.hash) {
  var target = $(window.location.hash);
  navigateToTarget(target);
 }

 $('.nav-primary a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    //console.log("testing");
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  var target = $(href.substr(href.indexOf("#")));
  navigateToTarget(target);
 });
});

function navigateToTarget(target) {
 if( target.length ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: target.offset().top - 155
  }, 1000);
 }
}
```

I read on another stackoverflow thread that firefox doesn't like when function() is missing 'event' inside but I tried that as well with no noticeable change whatsoever.

So, for testing purposes, go ahead and click any of the beginner links on the nav menu on both chrome and firefox to appreciate the difference.

Any help or pointers towards a solution would be greatly appreciated

Regards
Sotkra

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `event.preventDefault()` inside the `navigateToTarget` function, and there is no variable named `event` there.

It works on Chrome (and probably on IE), because they have a global property `window.event`, but that property is not cross browser, and it won't work on browsers that don't have this property.

You should remove the `event.preventDefault()` and everything is gonna work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Buzinas. I was unaware of the whole window.event situation. I will pay more attention to details of this type.

Comment: Whoah, I made the mistake of not triple checking everything before selecting the answer as the correct one. The code will now fail to work outside of the /guides/ page. If I'm I'm somewhere other than the guides page, clicking on a menu link won't trigger anything. If I'm in the guides page, it works alright.

Comment: Ok, the crux of the matter was simply getting rid of event.preventDefault(); I'll tick back your question but I suggest you add my note above to give it more visibility. Cheers and thanks again.